# Django - Generic Views - Object_list - What's the benefit?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I want to use the [object_list generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list).  But I can't tell what benefit it gives me besides pagination?  It seems like I still need to write my own template?

How is this faster than writing my own view? Am I missing something?

If it is worth using and I do have to write my own template, what is supposed to be in the template?  I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than one model, it saves you some time duplicating a similar view and template. Say you write an app with 15 models, you still only need 1 generic view and 1 template to show all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in thinking that the function-based generic views do not save you very much. As soon as you need just a little bit of customization you end up writing the view yourself. You should also note that they deprecated in Django 1.3 and there is a [migration guide](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/).

On the other hand the new [class-based generic views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/) in 1.3 are very handy. You can write the same list view logic and swap out a response mix-in to render an Excel spreadsheet or return JSON instead of rendering a template.